# How do i write a case statement to subtract 5 hours from datetime if it's before day light saving and subtract 4 hours if after

Tags: mysql, ansi-sql

I need to subtract 5 hours if the datetime falls before `03/09/2014` saving and 4 hours if it's after `03/09/2014`. It's in a case statement this is what I have so far but it's only hitting the first when and not working with the second when.

```
max(
  Case 
       when aa.status_id=10 and aa.created_at <'3/09/2014'
            then DATE_SUB(aa.created_at,  interval 4 HOUR) 
       when aa.status_id=10 and aa.created_at >'3/09/2014'
            then DATE_SUB(aa.created_at,  interval 4 HOUR)
       else null
  end )as  form_Receieved
```

Comment: I have a typo when it's less 03/09/2014 is 5 hours and greater 03/09/2014 is 4 hours

Comment: You might not be seeing correct result because you are subtracting 4 in both cases.

Comment: no I fixed that..It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

first you are substracting 4 hours from date ! which will not work , it must be datetime.

second you comparing between datetime column and date . you have to convert it to datetime. or make it same as your column format.

```
      when aa.status_id=10 and aa.created_at <'2014-03-09 00:00:00'
```

assuming that created_at is datetime column because you didnt show your table and columns structure.

Comment: I changed it to your format and I'm subtracting but my     created > 03/09/2014 00:00:00

Comment: oops.. I wasn't done is an hour behind I'm getting 13 instead of 14.

Comment: if you post some sample data and wished result. would be much better.